# Adding Kinetise service on Bluemix answers with 500 error

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud

When trying to add the Kinetise Service from the Bluemix Catalog, a pop-up appears saying:
Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error 500 received from broker url https://bluemix.marketplace.ibmcloud.com/api/custom/cloudfoundry/v2/service_instances/6b04405f-96d7-413a-91f2-92f036fc0bf7"}

I haven't found any pb recorded on the Bluemix Status page. 
I'm currently on US-South.

Answer (score 1):

This problem depends most likely by some issues in responding at the broker side.
Could you please open a ticket at Bluemix support using one of the following methods:

1. Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the
   upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI. After opening the support
   widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of
   assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
2. Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a
   separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you
   cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget. Go to
   http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is being worked out by the Kinetise team. Will update you as soon the service becomes available.